# tabla sin relacionar en una base de datos relacional?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones

tengo una duda... y es que quisiera saber si existen casos en que (usando una base de datos relacional como MySql) puedan haber tablas sin relacionar. Por ejemplo: modelando un una pequeña tienda virtual, tengo tablas como productos, clientes, proveedores (relacionadas entre sí), pero también debo realizar una integración con Instagram y entonces quería guardar el token en la Base de datos, por lo que pensaba crear una tabla que se llame integraciones (o algo parecido) donde tenga 2 campos, que serían nombre (en este caso instagram) y el token de dicha api, pero es que no veo con que podría estar relacionada esta tabla, es decir, solo sería una tabla para guardar la info de las integraciones que realice con otras API externas.

Entonces mi pregunta es básicamente; en una tabla relacional podrían existir tablas aisladas, con "aisladas" me refiero a que no estén relacionadas con ninguna tabla? eso estaría correcto?

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar con esta duda.

Comment: La respuesta corta es si, pueden existir tablas son relacionarse con otras, el que lo estén o no depende de tus reglas de negocio, si claramente tienes justificación para lo que mencionas entonces adelante, en caso contrario te invito a qué analices de nuevo

Comment: Gracias por responder. A simple vista, en un modelo como el que mencioné como lo verías tu? la cuenta de instagram que se de sea vincular es la de la empresa (solo esa) no es que son varías por usuarios ni nada de eso, es por eso que planteo que no esté relacionada con nada, por que es que en realidad no veo con que relacionarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, por supuesto. Es más, puedes relacionar una tabla con otra de forma implícita estableciéndolo en la definición de las tablas, etc. pero también puedes hacerlo sin declararlo sabiendo tú que campos corresponden a otros. Actuando unos como clave de indexación.

Hasta puedes tener todas las tablas sin relacionar y ser una DB en la que solo tú conoces la relación entre las tablas. Lo aconsejable obviamente es tener todo relacionado en la definición de la DB pero requiere una gran planificación.

Por experiencia te digo que se suele hacer un mitad y mitad dependiendo claro está del diseño, tipo de datos, etc.

Comment: Gracias por responder. A simple vista, en un modelo como el que mencioné como lo verías tu? la cuenta de instagram que se de sea vincular es la de la empresa (solo esa) no es que son varías por usuarios ni nada de eso, es por eso que planteo que no esté relacionada con nada, por que es que en realidad no veo con que relacionarla

Comment: Pues si esa tabla de integraciones no tiene nada que ver con el resto de datos de las demás tablas no la relaciones con nada. No tendría sentido. Además, más adelante siempre podrás hacer cambios en caso contrario.

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias amigo.